# Insert only new records that are added to TABLE A into TABLE B

Tags: sql, insert

Presently I have 2 tables in a SQL database: Table A and Table B
I am using the syntax

```
Insert Into TABLE B
Select id, col, col, col......
From TABLE A
Where id NOT IN (SELECT id from TABLE B)
End;
```

This syntax works great. However, if I delete a record that is in TABLE B, the above code would in return, insert the deleted record back into TABLE B. I do not want this to happen. Is there another way to insert a record that is NOT IN TABLE B "only once". It should basically ignore all other previously inserted records which were inserted into TABLE B. If it was deleted it should not be inserted a second time.

I want it to only insert only new records added to TABLE A.

Comment: Could you track the ID of deleted rows in separate table, thus being able to exclude from re-inserting, or track the last inserted ID in table A and only insert to table B for new rows where it's higher. Or alternatively use a `Trigger` to insert into Table B

Comment: You can add another `not in/not exists` predicate to check the id in the table itself (`B`). Or delete with flags logically, not physically

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is consecutive integer then you can use:

```
Insert Into TABLE B
Select id, col, col, col......
From TABLE A
where ID > select(max(id) from table B)
```